# Not sure if i'm using oop in javascript correctly

Tags: javascript, class, oop, data-binding, components

Im learning OOP and decided to create a project using it. I feel like I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly.

```js
const btnCalculate = document.getElementById('work');
const spanOne = document.querySelector('.first');
const spanTwo = document.querySelector('.second');

class PayDay{
    constructor(hours, payRate){
        this.hours = hours;
        this.payRate = payRate;
      
       this.execute = ()=>{
            let grossPay = (hours * payRate)
            let deduction = grossPay * 0.0765
            if(isNaN(deduction)){
                document.querySelector('.result').textContent = "Enter a number"
            }
            else {
                document.querySelector('.result').textContent =  '$' + Math.floor(grossPay - deduction);
                document.querySelector('.third').textContent = '(federal income taxes not included)';
            }
        }
    }
}

btnCalculate.onclick = ()=>{
    const hoursWorked = parseInt(document.getElementById('hrsWorked').value);
    const hourlyPay = parseInt(document.getElementById('hourly').value);
    let userOne= new PayDay(hoursWorked, hourlyPay);
    userOne.execute()
}
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body{
  background: #828189;
}

.main{
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    padding-bottom: 10%;
    background: #d8ccd0;
    border: 5px solid #a18d8c;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.group{
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row ;
}
.contain{
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
div{
    width:50%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;

}
h1{
    margin-top:2%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #d8ccd0;
    font-size: 5rem;
    text-shadow: -4px -4px #a18d8c;
}
input{
    width: 24%;
    background: #e1e2ee;
    padding: 1%;
    color: #a18d8c;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.result{
  text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    color: #a18d8c;
    font-size: 5rem;
}
.third{
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: #a18d8c;
}
#work{
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    padding: .5%;
    background: #e1e2ee;
    color: #a18d8c;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Calculate net pay</h1>
<section class='main'>
    <div>
        <input id="hrsWorked" type="text" placeholder='Enter Hours Worked' >
        <input id="hourly" type="text" placeholder="Enter Hourly Rate">
    </div>

    <button id="work">Enter</button>
  <div class="contain">
    <span class="result"></span>
    <span class="third"></span>
  </div>

</section>
```

I just created a simple tax calculator project trying to use oop, I'm not sure if I used OOP correctly.

The part that's giving me doubt is the fact that I created the userOne variable to be able to run the code inside the class.

Is there another way to access the properties and methods with having to create the userOne variable?

Any tips will help.

Comment: on the last sentence meant to put 'Without having to create the userOne variable'

Comment: OOP means literally objected-oriented programming and you created `userOne` object, so it's fine. There are problems with your code but creating the object variable is not one of them.

Comment: I see no problem with this at al in terms of OOP.  You are creating and using objects properly.  You could easily create more objects if you needed to by initializing more classes

Comment: What you did with the `userOne` is that you instanciated an object. A class is virtually just a description of the variables (class variables) and their functions (methods). They cannot be accessed or worked with. Only after you instanciate an object it comes to "life". So you did everthing right. (As always: sometimes there are exceptions from these rules.)

Comment: Avoid hardcoding stuff like `document.querySelector('.result')` into a Class.

Comment: The OP's use case is best described as _implementing an abstraction which handles DOM-based data in- and output and the calculation of the output-data_. **Component** would be a word which fits the subject. What the OP's solution lacks is code-reuse, due to some hard wired DOM-queries, but especially due to not integrating the calculate button into the component. The usage of `id` attributes also is a hindrance. In addition any OO and component based approach does not necessarily need to be implemented via class syntax. The latter just offers a special kind of abstraction on the matter of OOP.

Comment: thanks everyone for the tips. i still have a lot to learn

Answer (score 2):

There are always tons of small details you can fight about with your colleagues when it comes to "doing OOP right", but I think there are two issues with your code that most people would agree with:

The first is that `execute` is declared as a property, not a real class method, which would look like this:

```
class PayDay{
  constructor(hours, payRate){
    this.hours = hours;
    this.payRate = payRate;
  }
  
  execute(){
    const grossPay = this.hours * this.payRate
    ...
  }
}
```

Declaring it as a class method holding an arrow function has several downsides:

- every instance has its own declaration of the method (instead of sharing one single declaration provided by the shared prototype), which is inefficient
- overriding `execute` when extending the class becomes more complicated when the new version builds upon the old version (you cannot use `super.execute()` or `PayDay.prototype.execute()`)
- in this particular implementation, `execute` binds the `hours` and `payRate` values provided to the constructor. If you change the values later on, the data written by `execute` does not reflect the object's state

The second issue will seem pedantic, but it is really important. Note that objects are semantic units, they represent entities in the domain. And in that sense, it is understandable that a payday's data includes the number of hours and an hourly wage. But what does it mean to execute a payday? 
When you look at the code, the method calculates a total amount and outputs it. Nothing gets executed here. So the name is wrong. A more fitting name would be something like `writeNetPayToTag()`.

Now we could start arguing if a PayDay writes to a tag at all, or if it isn't rather a TagWriter or a PrintablePayDayData that does it, but I don't want to, because it enters the realm of opinion vs specific use case. I'd rather note that you can (and should) change things when you find out that they don't work well. Others might see this differently, but I think they'd still agree with the first two points.

Comment: All good points. I would add that PayDay doesn't have a good separation of concerns when it comes to populating the view. It's mainly a model object in the sense of model-view-controller, but it updates the view. I would call the method `calculate()` or something like that, and just have it return the result. And then the code that uses it could update the view.

Comment: @MoritzRingler thank you, i changed the names of variables and methods to  make it easier to see what they do. also removed the method out of the constructor, idk how i didnt realize i was doing that wrong. this journey to learn how to code has been difficult so this feed back really helps

Answer (score -1):

***Edit** ... in response to a direct comment of the OP ...*

> *"you said that the use of an id attribute is a hindrance. can you clarify more on that?"* – Gzus24

> > *"@Gzus24 ... 1/3 ... An approach like chosen by you, which just connects some data and a method, relies on additional scripts, for e.g. click event handling, which are not connected to the abstraction. What happens in such a handler-function actually entirely contradicts the class-based abstraction since within each handler-invocation one has to create a `PayDay`-instance just in order to be able to execute the payment calculation. And just for that one has to query the necessary elements and to parse the needed values within the handler function."* – Peter Seliger
>
> > *"@Gzus24 ... 2/3 ... At this point one could just pass these values to a simple calculating function instead of having to invoke the instance's `execute`. The latter method also does not just calculate, it queries elements too and writes values. There is no separation of concerns. And on top, the most important element queries are based on `id` values. Thus, one could never write a self containing `Calculator`-component which could be re-used a second time on one and the same page. I know, this sounds hypothetical, but the effects on the chosen approach and implementation, in case one does ..."* – Peter Seliger
>
> > *"@Gzus24 ... 3/3 ... consider such scenarios, are tremendous. An entirely encapsulated, self contained component which also does handle UI events entirely by itself can only rely on a generic markup, thus, ... no `id`-attributes, neither for targeting nor for querying. It also does separate tasks. There are query tasks which are only responsible for that. Calculation and event-handling tasks as well, each dedicated to exactly one thing. Clean code regardless of whether being OO or something else does never intermingle such responsibilities in one and the same task/procedure/operation/function."* – Peter Seliger

---

The OP's use case is best described as ... *"implementing an abstraction which handles DOM-based data in- and output and the calculation of the output-data"*. **Component** would be a word which fits the subject.

**What the OP's solution lacks is code-reuse**, due to some hard-wired DOM-queries, but especially due to not integrating the calculate button into the component. The usage of (as well hard-wired) `id` attributes also is a hindrance. In addition any OO and component based approach does not necessarily need to be implemented via class syntax. The latter just offers a special kind of abstraction on the matter of OOP.

The next provided solution implements the above mentioned component-based approach via a generic component-markup and re-usable functionality and [component-specific data which is/gets bound to each component's sole handler function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) where the data-binding covers the OO part of this approach.

```js
function computePayment(hours, rate, deductionFactor) {
  const grossPay = hours * rate;
  const deduction = grossPay * deductionFactor;

  return Math.floor(grossPay - deduction);
}

function queryComponentElements(rootNode) {
  return {
    elmHours: rootNode.querySelector('[data-total-hours]'),
    elmRate: rootNode.querySelector('[data-hourly-rate]'),
    elmOutput: rootNode.querySelector('[data-currency-symbol]'),
    // elmCalculate: rootNode.querySelector('[data-calculate]'),
  };
}
function preventComponentSubmit(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault;
  return false;
}

function enhanceComponentUsability(elmHours, elmRate, elmOutput) {
  // - for UX and accessibility reasons an <output/> element ...
  elmHours.id = crypto?.randomUUID();
  elmRate.id = crypto?.randomUUID();
  //   ... was chosen which works best with the `for`-attribute
  //   which relates the output's input-elements via their `id`s.
  elmOutput.setAttribute(
    'for', [elmHours.id, elmRate.id].join(' ')
  );
}

function handleInputChangeFromBoundComponentData() {
  const {
    elmHours, elmRate, elmOutput, deductionFactor, currencySymbol,
  } = this;

  elmOutput.value = [
    currencySymbol,
    computePayment(
      parseFloat(elmHours.value),
      parseFloat(elmRate.value),
      deductionFactor,
    ),
  ].join(' ');
}

function initializeCalculatorComponent(rootNode) {
  const {
    elmHours, elmRate, elmOutput/*, elmCalculate*/,
  } = queryComponentElements(rootNode);

  const { currencySymbol = 'XXX' } = elmOutput.dataset;
  let { deductionFactor } = elmOutput.dataset;

  deductionFactor = parseFloat(deductionFactor);
  deductionFactor = Number.isNaN(deductionFactor)
    && .0765 || deductionFactor;

  enhanceComponentUsability(elmHours, elmRate, elmOutput);

  // - initial payment calculation
  //   (can handle initiallay provided input values).
  handleInputChangeFromBoundComponentData.call({
    elmHours, elmRate, elmOutput, deductionFactor, currencySymbol,
  });

  // - payment related event handling needs a component's data-binding.
  const handleInputChange =
    handleInputChangeFromBoundComponentData.bind({
      elmHours, elmRate, elmOutput, deductionFactor, currencySymbol,
    });

  // - event handling.
  elmHours.addEventListener('input', handleInputChange);
  elmRate.addEventListener('input', handleInputChange);

  rootNode.addEventListener('submit', preventComponentSubmit);
}

document
  .querySelectorAll('[data-netpay-calculator]')
  .forEach(initializeCalculatorComponent);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
form { margin-bottom: 7px; }
fieldset { padding-bottom: 0; }
p { margin: 3px 0 7px 0; }
```

```html
<form data-netpay-calculator>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Calculate net pay</legend>

    <label>
      <span>Hours Worked</span>
      <input
        data-total-hours type="number"
        value="0" min="0" max="120" step=".25"
        placeholder="Enter hours worked"
      />
    </label>
    <label>
      <span>Hourly Rate</span>
      <input
        data-hourly-rate type="number"
        value="0" min="5" max="1000" step=".5"
        placeholder="Enter hourly rate"
      />
    </label>

    <!-- <button data-calculate>Calculate</button> //-->
    <p>
      <output
        data-currency-symbol="$"
        data-deduction-factor="0.0765"
      >$ 0</output>
      <em>(federal income taxes not included)</em>
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>

<form data-netpay-calculator>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Calculate net pay</legend>

    <label>
      <span>Hours Worked</span>
      <input
        data-total-hours type="number"
        value="40" min="0" max="120" step=".25"
        placeholder="Enter hours worked"
      />
    </label>
    <label>
      <span>Hourly Rate</span>
      <input
        data-hourly-rate type="number"
        value="120" min="5" max="1000" step=".5"
        placeholder="Enter hourly rate"
      />
    </label>

    <!-- <button data-calculate>Calculate</button> //-->
    <p>
      <output
        data-currency-symbol="£"
        data-deduction-factor="0.09"
      >$ 0</output><!--
      <em>(federal income taxes not included)</em> //-->
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Utilizing [class-syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) for a component based approach does not prevent the still necessary data-binding for any component-specific event-handling. But it does offer a for some people more convenient way via [*private fields*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields), a prototypal handler function and a simple component binding.

The above example-code implemented by class-syntax then might look like this ...

```js
function computePayment(hours, rate, deductionFactor) {
  const grossPay = hours * rate;
  const deduction = grossPay * deductionFactor;

  return Math.floor(grossPay - deduction);
}

function queryComponentElements(rootNode) {
  return {
    elmHours: rootNode.querySelector('[data-total-hours]'),
    elmRate: rootNode.querySelector('[data-hourly-rate]'),
    elmOutput: rootNode.querySelector('[data-currency-symbol]'),
    // elmCalculate: rootNode.querySelector('[data-calculate]'),
  };
}
function preventComponentSubmit(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault;
  return false;
}

function enhanceComponentUsability(elmHours, elmRate, elmOutput) {
  // - for UX and accessibility reasons an <output/> element ...
  elmHours.id = crypto?.randomUUID();
  elmRate.id = crypto?.randomUUID();
  //   ... was chosen which works best with the `for`-attribute
  //   which relates the output's input-elements via their `id`s.
  elmOutput.setAttribute(
    'for', [elmHours.id, elmRate.id].join(' ')
  );
}
function initializeComponent(component, rootNode, elmHours, elmRate) {
  // - initial payment calculation
  //   (can handle initiallay provided input values).
  component.handleInputChange();

  // - payment related event handling needs `this`/`component` binding.
  const handleInputChange = component.handleInputChange.bind(component);

  // - event handling.
  elmHours.addEventListener('input', handleInputChange);
  elmRate.addEventListener('input', handleInputChange);

  rootNode.addEventListener('submit', preventComponentSubmit);
}

class NetPayCalculator {
  // private fields.
  #elmHours;
  #elmRate;
  #elmOutput;
  #currencySymbol;
  #deductionFactor;

  constructor(rootNode) {
    const {
      elmHours, elmRate, elmOutput/*, elmCalculate*/,
    } = queryComponentElements(rootNode);

    this.#elmHours = elmHours;
    this.#elmRate = elmRate;
    this.#elmOutput = elmOutput;

    let { deductionFactor } = elmOutput.dataset;
    deductionFactor = parseFloat(deductionFactor);

    this.#deductionFactor = Number.isNaN(deductionFactor)
      && .0765 || deductionFactor;

    this.#currencySymbol = elmOutput.dataset.currencySymbol;

    enhanceComponentUsability(elmHours, elmRate, elmOutput);
    initializeComponent(this, rootNode, elmHours, elmRate);
  }
  // prototypal method with private field access.
  handleInputChange() {
    this.#elmOutput.value = [
      this.#currencySymbol,
      computePayment(
        parseFloat(this.#elmHours.value),
        parseFloat(this.#elmRate.value),
        this.#deductionFactor,
      ),
    ].join(' ');
  }
  // static initialize or create method.
  static create(rootNode) {
    new NetPayCalculator(rootNode);
  }
}

document
  .querySelectorAll('[data-netpay-calculator]')
  .forEach(NetPayCalculator.create);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
form { margin-bottom: 7px; }
fieldset { padding-bottom: 0; }
p { margin: 3px 0 7px 0; }
```

```html
<form data-netpay-calculator>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Calculate net pay</legend>

    <label>
      <span>Hours Worked</span>
      <input
        data-total-hours type="number"
        value="0" min="0" max="120" step=".25"
        placeholder="Enter hours worked"
      />
    </label>
    <label>
      <span>Hourly Rate</span>
      <input
        data-hourly-rate type="number"
        value="0" min="5" max="1000" step=".5"
        placeholder="Enter hourly rate"
      />
    </label>

    <!-- <button data-calculate>Calculate</button> //-->
    <p>
      <output
        data-currency-symbol="$"
        data-deduction-factor="0.0765"
      >$ 0</output>
      <em>(federal income taxes not included)</em>
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>

<form data-netpay-calculator>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Calculate net pay</legend>

    <label>
      <span>Hours Worked</span>
      <input
        data-total-hours type="number"
        value="40" min="0" max="120" step=".25"
        placeholder="Enter hours worked"
      />
    </label>
    <label>
      <span>Hourly Rate</span>
      <input
        data-hourly-rate type="number"
        value="120" min="5" max="1000" step=".5"
        placeholder="Enter hourly rate"
      />
    </label>

    <!-- <button data-calculate>Calculate</button> //-->
    <p>
      <output
        data-currency-symbol="£"
        data-deduction-factor="0.09"
      >$ 0</output><!--
      <em>(federal income taxes not included)</em> //-->
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: And the uncommented -1vote was rightfully earned for exactly which technical fault or exactly which provided substantially wrong comment on the OP's implementation? An uncommented negative vote on an answer which sheds light from different angles of view on a very specific matter/topic leaves not only the audience puzzled about where the errors are to be located; it also does not allow any improvements, neither by the author nor by some other willing contributor.

Comment: you said that the use of an id attribute is a hindrance. can you clarify more on that?

Comment: @Gzus24 ... 1/3 ... An approach like chosen by you, which just connects some data and a method, relies on additional scripts, for e.g. click event handling, which are not connected to the abstraction. What happens in such a handler-function actually entirely contradicts the class-based abstraction since within each handler-invocation one has to create a `PayDay`-instance just in order to be able to `execute` the payment calculation. And just for that one has to query the necessary elements and to parse the needed values within the handler function.

Comment: @Gzus24 ... 2/3 ... At this point one could just pass these values to a simple calculating function instead of having to invoke the instance's `execute`. The latter method also does not just calculate, it queries elements too and writes values. There is no separation of concerns. And on top, the most important element queries are based on `id` values. Thus, one could never write a self containing `Calculator`-component which could be re-used a second time on one and the same page. I know, this sounds hypothetical, but the effects on the chosen approach and implementation, in case one does ...

Comment: @Gzus24 ... 3/3 ... consider such scenarios, are tremendous. An entirely encapsulated, self contained component which also does handle UI events entirely by itself can only rely on a generic markup, thus, ... no `id`-attributes, neither for targeting nor for querying. It also does separate tasks. There are query tasks which are only responsible for that. Calculation and event-handling tasks as well, each dedicated to exactly one thing. Clean code regardless of whether being OO or something else does never intermingle such responsibilities in one and the same task/procedure/operation/function.

Comment: I'm a couple months into learning to code, so any feed back is appreciated. some of the things you mention are not easy for me to understand right now but in time i hope to be able to fully understand

Comment: My goal with this project was to practice using OOP, so that's why I kept it to just using the class in order to get this tax calculator to work. I do really appreciate the feed back. Is there any tips you can give me to better improve?

Comment: What I can say on the matter of [**OOP**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) is that one foremost should accept that one deals with a [**programming-paradigm**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_paradigm) which sits on the **concept of object-orientation**. Neither is in need of the [_class concept_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_programming)). [Alan Kay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Kay) stated in 2003 _"OOP to me means only messaging, local retention and protection and hiding of state-process, and extreme late-binding of all things."_